# AngularJS - add or edit (dynamic) data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dynamic

OK, so I have a case, where let's say there's a report and there can be several users attached to the report. Users are of course objects, so we have three types of info:
title (string)
description (string)
involved (array of objects)

Now, there's already a pre-defined array of objects that user can choose from, so the natural way is to use select with ng-option, which I've done.
When adding an involved person, user can dynamically choose how many people he wants to add. When editing a specific report, user can change the value of involved person, delete a person or add new one.

So far, I've came up with this (it's a simulation where you edit an existing report, these values come from a web service):
http://jsbin.com/poqiheputa/1/edit

As evident, if I change an existing person involved and submit the data, the value won't be changed. If I add a person and set it to a value, then add another person, the previous value disappears. I'm totally in the dark here, so any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is the way you're using `ng-model` in your `select` that's contained in a `ng-repeat`. The explanation is a bit involved, but I'll try nevertheless.

`ng-repeat` creates a new scope for each of the iterations. Within a single iteration's scope, you then create a `select` with a `ng-model` of `i`. But what you don't realize is that the `ng-model` binding gets created within that scope, not the parent scope. Now, when you modify the `involved` collection, `ng-repeat` retriggers and the child scopes get recreated. Since the value never propagated to the parent scope, it's now lost. You can observe this in action by adding a `{{involved|json}}` somewhere.

There are a couple of ways to fix this.

The general rule of thumb is that you should have a dot in your `ng-model`, always. Practically this means that your `ng-model` bindings should refer to a property on an object, like so: `ng-model="model.property"` and your parent scope should have a property named `model`. In your case, however, `ng-model="involved[$index]"` seems like a better choice.

The reason for all this has to do with prototypical inheritance. When you create a child scope, it inherits properties from its parent scope, like so:

```
parent.foo = 1;

child.foo === 1; // this is true even if nobody sets child.foo
```

However, if you set the value of a child's property, it overrides it only within the child scope:

```
parent.foo = 1;

child.foo === 1; // true
child.foo = 2;

child.foo === 2; // true
parent.foo === 1; // still true -- child now has its own, overriding foo property
```

But if you use objects or arrays, things act a bit differently:

```
parent.foo = { bar = 1 };

child.foo.bar === 1; // true
child.foo.bar = 2;

parent.foo.bar === 2; // true!
```

This might seem a bit surprising, but the reason is actually very simple: the child scope inherits the `foo` object reference from its parent, and since it's a reference, assignment to one of its properties will propagate everywhere, like they should. And since arrays are also object references, the same logic holds for `involved[$index]` within your ng-repeat.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! I think I understand this a bit more. So my solution is as follows: http://jsbin.com/harajadowi/1/edit?html,js,output
(didn't know that objects can cause dupe in array as well)

Comment: Arrays are not sets, so you can add any value into an array multiple times, including object references.

Comment: I thought so too, but if you look at this example (without track by $index) and try to add another Bill, the console reports an error (dupe), however, with track by $index, no such error is presented. http://jsbin.com/vuhuyecaxi/1/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Ah, that's not related to arrays as such, but rather a feature of ng-repeat.